# Reference: Topology on Ind-object

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, category-theory

In some articles I've recently seen authors mention that pro-finite groups or pro-finite algebras possess a topology, but they do not explicitly describe it.

I was wondering how is the topology defined, and is the finite condition needed.   Moreover can a dual construction be given to define a topology on an arbitrary inductive system in say the category of $R$-algebras?

References are also greatly appreciated :)

Comment: "but they do not explicitly describe it." ?! Every introduction to pro-finite groups describes this. Have you look at at least one? The topology is the subspace topology of the product topology.

Comment: Actually, I only looked at papers on the pro-finite algebra construction, now that you mention it, I just had some luck looking up the pro-finite group construction :)

Comment: It's easy to define the topology: just calculate the corresponding colimit or limit in $\mathbf{Top}$. The real question is whether it is useful or not. It seems to be a massive coincidence that continuous maps of profinite sets are precisely the morphisms of pro-objects as defined abstractly.